# Getting an error with using scipy.inegrated.solve_ivp

Tags: python

im getting an error with scipy.inegrated.solve_ivp if theres a better way to post code tell me cause i cant get it to work. Ive looked at a friends code just like it to see if there was any mistakes and i dont see any.

Comment: Please post the complete error message that you see. If the error message includes a line number pointing to where the error is, post the code around that line as well.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.